# Cube arrow lattice

Tags: modifiers

How can I put an arrow in the middle of each side of the cube. I basically need a lattice and an arrow in the middle on each side. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you illustrate what you are trying to achieve? Maybe edit your question and provide some reference images of what you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cube > Create a texture with an alpha channel > UV Unwrap the cube > Create a material using the texture.
[image]

Comment: Almost positive this is not what the user wants, but my upvote for the funny answer and making me laugh

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos That means a lot... You are a force.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think you have to do it like this:

1. Select the face from what you want to put the arrow through.
2. Use the shortcut shift+S
3. Choose otion called "cursor to active"

This put your 3Dcursor exactly in the middle of a face. Then you can add an arrow.

Comment: I'm really new in Blender and I know I must look at all tutoriale but I absolutely need this picture.

1. Tab(Edit Modus)
2. Face Select
3. Shift + S, then Select Cursor to Active
4. Then in Object Mode, Shift+A, Select Empty, then Single Arrow
5. Object Mode-Add Modifier-Wireframe (beacause I need only the frame from cube)